System.NullReferenceException is thrown when I try to change selection in Datagridview.ComboboxColumn
My problem is that when I click comboboxcolumn tbe second time, I have NullReferenceException in Program.cs, on the Application.Run line. I have Windows Form application and on the main form i have DataGridView connected to SQL Server Database. One of DataGridView columns is ComboboxColumn, but I work with it as actual Combobox. I made transformation with EditingControlShowing event and created severalevents for ComboBox:
private void dgrv1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   var cb = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
   cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= this.cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
   cb.SelectedIndexChanged += this.cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
   cb.DropDown -= this.cb_DropDown;
   cb.DropDown += this.cb_DropDown;
   cb.DropDownClosed -= this.cb_DropDownClosed;
   cb.DropDownClosed += this.cb_DropDownClosed;
}

private void cb_DropDown (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ var cb = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
   string text = cb.text; }
private void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ var cb = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
   int ind = cb.SelectedIndex; 
   dgrv1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
   dgrv1.EndEdit;}
private void cb_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ var cb = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
   dgrv1.EndEdit; }

Exception is trown where I click ComboBoxColumn second time regardless of my actions (if I changed selected item in list or not). When I do it first time all events work correctly. When EditingControlShowing event is not working, i don't have this exception.
System.NullReferenceException
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridView.InitializeEditingControlValue(DataGridViewCellStyle& dataGridViewCellStyle, DatagridViewCell dataGridViewCell)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridView.BeginEditInternal(Boolean selectAll)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridView.BeginEdit(Boolean selectAll)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridViewComboBoxCell.OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridView.OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DatatGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int2 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr Iparam)
 at System.Windows.Forms.OnSafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnSafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32            reason, Int32 pvLoopdata)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.TreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.TreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
 at MyProject.Program.Main() in <путь к папке решения>\MyProject\Program.cs:line19


Is the control actually a DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl? I miss a check for null on cb in your EditingControlShowing handler.

Could you please write the full sentence, how I should make this check?

I meant you should check that the variable is not null like in the official documentation See the code sample.

I just made this check. When I click ComboBoxColumn the first time, this sentence returns true, but the second time it doesn't even reach this line and throw exception

It turned out that the problem was in the extra EndEdit method in the SelectedIndexChanged event. It is not needed there, because editing is completed by the DropDownClosed event, and if we complete editing the same cell twice, then the methods conflict.
